# If A is true then B must also be true

Tags: logic

What if in the statement, "If A is true then B must also be true," A & B are related but, "B must also be true," is not necessarily true because other possibilities exist? In other words, A being true means B could be true but not necessarily.

Comment: What you mean by "what if"?

Comment: The possibility that “A and not-B” is true means that “A therefore B” is false.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of something like □A→□B, if A is necessarily true then B is necessarily true. Then if A is true only contingently (in some possible world) B may not be (in the same world), i.e. □(A→B) does not follow. In other words, if A is true by accident B could be true, but not necessarily. "If A is true then B must also be true" is ambiguously phrased, it is unclear where the necessity symbol □ is intended to be, if anywhere at all.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be interested in the following topics:

- [Defeasible logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defeasible_logic) allows arguments to *defeat* other arguments, so that at first we may conclude C, and then later more evidence arises, "defeating" the first argument, and we conclude not C.
- [Non-monotonic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-monotonic_logic) is the category of logic that defeasible logic falls into.
- [Argument mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_map) diagrams informal arguments in which claims lend or detract support from other claims, rather than having a strict deductive implication.

Answer (score 1):

By the end of your question, what you are getting at with "A being true means B could be true but not necessarily" can be formalized as "if A then possibly B":

```
A → ◊B
```

The logic of "possibly" and "necessarily" is called [modal logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/). There's a lot of "what-ifs" that follow from that sentence. For example, if follows that, if B is impossible, then A is false:

```
□(¬B) → ¬A
```